# how to get reliable list of uninstalled packages android

Tags: android

I am getting list of packages using packagemanager with `GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES` flag,

```
  PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

    List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES);
```

but since it returns:  "information about all applications (even uninstalled ones) which have data directories." I am unable to get reliable list of previously uninstalled package **including apps that didn't left a data directory behind**.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer : I didn't try this solution, but it may help (requires Android 5)

With android 5, there is this new API : [UsageStatsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html) with this method :

[`usageStatsManager.queryAndAggregateUsageStats(startTime,endTime)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html#queryAndAggregateUsageStats(long,%20long))

returning an `Map` where keys are the package name (and values are usage statistics). Hopefully, this will include uninstalled apps (but I'm not sure !). Of course you won't get the `AppInfo` (only the package name)

Note also this [important remark](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html) about required permissions:

> NOTE: This API requires the permission android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS, which is a system-level permission and will not be granted to third-party apps. However, declaring the permission implies intention to use the API and the user of the device can grant permission through the Settings application.